# WinApi FormatMessage causes segfault

Tags: c++, winapi, segmentation-fault, mingw, codeblocks

I use CodeBlocks and Mingw: g++ version is 4.7.1

The example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (see the last example, just before 'Requirements' section):

```
// Formats a message string using the specified message and variable
// list of arguments.
LPWSTR GetFormattedMessage(LPWSTR pMessage, ...)
{
   LPWSTR pBuffer = NULL;

   va_list args = NULL;
   va_start(args, pMessage);

   FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_STRING |
              FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER,
              pMessage, 
              0,
              0,
              (LPWSTR)&pBuffer, 
              0, 
              &args);

   va_end(args);

   return pBuffer;
}
```

It segfaults on call to FormatMessage.
Do you have any idea why is this happening and how I can fix this?

This is how I call it:

```
int x = 3, y = 5;
GetFormattedMessage(_T("%1 : %2"), x, y);
```

I used FormatMessage because I cannot use _stprintf function on mingw,_stprintf is a define to swprintf and swprintf itselft is not defined there as a fix to some of there bugs %)

Comment: Casting things to fix compiler errors isn't a solution. You need to pass in a buffer it can fill.

Comment: Casting `(LPWSTR)&pBuffer` is ok. It's required by Microsoft. Read msdn:
The lpBuffer parameter is a pointer to an LPTSTR; you must cast the pointer to an LPTSTR (for example, (LPTSTR)&lpBuffer).

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't caused by the contents of `pMessage` not matching the passed arguments?

Comment: @Arks, Never mind, I missed the buffer allocation flag and the fact that it wasn't being used to translate an error code (which is the only thing I ever see it used for).

Comment: @The Dark, Maybe, I've editted my post and added a line showing how I call this function.

Comment: @chris, Ok. Btw, what do you mean by "the fact that it wasn't being used to translate an error code"?

Comment: @Arks, I mean the usual `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` usage.

Comment: `FormatMessage` is a poor choice, if you want a replacement for `swprintf`. A more appropriate match is [`StringCchVPrintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647546.aspx) and friends.

Comment: @IInspectable, thank you. I'll move to this function.

Answer (score 3):

FormatMessage requires that you pass the type information in the message string. If you don't it assumes that your parameters are C style strings. MSDN says:

> The default is to treat each value as a pointer to a null-terminated string.

As you are passing integers, rather than strings, your call should be something like:

```
GetFormattedMessage(_T("%1!d! : %2!d!"), x, y);
```

Comment: Thanks, missed that part.